# how to make ajax call in Jquery's delegate()

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a delegate function of JQuery to remove a row of a grid which is anchor tagged remove, as below

```
 $('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {

            // e.preventDefault();
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');   
        var htmlstring = tr.find("td").eq(0).html();
        alert(htmlstring);  
            jQuery.ajax(  //$.ajax( also not working
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UploadDocuments/Removefile",
                    data: "removefile=" + htmlstring, 
                 success: function(){
                      tr.remove();
                       }
                });
        });
```

this is where i am making delegate call in success function of JQuery

```
    success: function(result) {
 var htmlString = [result];
                for (i = 0; i < htmlString.length; i++) {
       $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a href=' + htmlString[i].no + '>' + htmlString[i].name+ '</a></td><td><a href=' + htmlString[i].no+ ' class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
}
           },
```

Now i want to make ajax call as shown but it is not hitting once i click remove ,but is loading initially.Also i need to pass  the data i.e the name of the deleted row.How can i get that value?
could any of you guys help me out! got stucked !! ;)

thanking you,

michaeld

Comment: you want to pass name of deleted row or text of that row?

Comment: it will be better if you post snippet of your html code...mainly th tr part which you are trying to remove

Comment: Hi Vivek , i have added the code and i need to pass the "result.childNodes[0].innerHTML" to controller ,but before that Ajax call is not making .How can i do that ? because that is the big issue for me. thanks

Comment: @michael- you can use `ShankarSangoli` code, just pass `0` in place `IndexOfNameColumn`. let me know it works for you or not.

Comment: @Vivek - my requirement is changed and edited the success function: , i need to pass htmlstring[i].no to controller? so i need to modify var tr,how can that be modified? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code-

```
$('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {

        // e.preventDefault();
          var tr =     $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(0).find('a').text().replace(/"/g,"").trim();  //line#3   
       var $this =  $(this);
        jQuery.ajax(  
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "UploadDocuments/Removefile",
                data: "removefile=" + tr //file name from line#3
                 success: function(){
                  $this.closest('tr').remove(); 
                   }
            });

    });
```

Comment: Hi vivek , it worked fine, both text() and html() are working in my code.now if tr = "new.txt" i need to pass data in tr as new.txt excluding the quotes. may be i need to use remove(), i will try that But my main problem is ajax call is not  making. how can i make that

Comment: remove `comma(,)` after `data: "removefile=" + htmlstring, ` in your ajax call..that extra comma means you are  going to give extra parameter but in reality you doesn't. so that's causing the problem

Comment: for success: i have added comma, now it is making ajax call, but the string passed tris as "\"new.txt\".

Comment: that's great to hear that finally your ajax started working :)...to remove double quotes see my updated answer.

Comment: hey vivek, file is not removing;) even i have put it outside the success also not removing.

Comment: what file ? you are talking about tr?

Comment: have you written this line in your code.`var $this =  $(this);
`..please try to write my code line by line as i have written

Comment: my mistake it's deleting..thank you so much vivek, u saved my day,one more thing ,if file name is "new.txt" i need to send as new.txt but it is going as "\"new.txt\",after adding replace() action method is taking as "new.txt" but want only new.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try this where IndexOfNameColumn points to the name column index.

```
$('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {

        // e.preventDefault();
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');   //line#3
var htmlstring = tr.find("td").eq(IndexOfNameColumn).html();
        jQuery.ajax(  //$.ajax( also not working
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "UploadDocuments/Removefile",
                data: "removefile=" + htmlstring //file name from line#3
            });
tr.remove();
    });
```

Comment: Hi Shankar ,Thanks for your reply , i have put alert popup for htmlstring it is not even popping up , i also tried like this but no luck .var stringhtml = $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(IndexOfNameColumn).html();  But my main problem is ajax call is not making how can i make ajax call inside delegate ?

Comment: @Michael - There was a spelling mistake I have edited my answer please check and accept my answer if it solves your problem thanks.

Comment: Hi shankar, i have added the editd answer to my code , it is not even removing the file from grid alert(htmlstring ); not even popping up.Also how to make ajax call ?

Comment: what is IndexOfNameColumn you setting in the code and where is the alert call in the js?

Comment: to which i need to set IndexOfNameColumn?  i thought it is predefined type which identifies the name .

Comment: it will be better if you post snippet of your html code...mainly th tr part which you are trying to remove

Comment: just pass 0 in place IndexOfNameColumn. let me know it works for you or not